# SQL Server : TOP along with Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, distinct

I have two tables `Products` and `PurchaseDetails`.

The schema for `Products` table is

```
ProductId  (primary key)
ProductName
CategoryId
Price
QuantityAvailable
```

The schema for `PurchaseDetails` table is

```
PurchaseId
EmailId
ProductId
QuantityPurchased
DateOfPurchase
```

The question asks me to find out the TOP 3 products that are purchased in large quantity.

I wrote this SQL query:

```
Select TOP 3 
    Distinct(ProductName), Price, QuantityPurchased
from 
    Product, PurchaseDetails
where 
    Product.ProductId = PurchaseDetails.ProductId
order by 
    QuantityPurchased DESC
```

But the above query throws an error. I fail to see why the error is being generated by the above query ?

Comment: You should probably SUM the quantity purchased for each product before taking the top 3. You are only taking the largest single purchases, which is why you are using DISTINCT.

Comment: Gives you what error exactly? Be specific.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query will give you the top 3 products that are purchased in large quantity

```
Select TOP 3 ProductName,sum(Price) as [price],sum(QuantityPurchased) as QuantityPurchased
    from Product , PurchaseDetails
    where Product.ProductId=PurchaseDetails.ProductId
    group by ProductName
    order by QuantityPurchased DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select TOP 3 ProductName,sum(Price) as [price],sum(QuantityPurchased) as QuantityPurchased
    from Product , PurchaseDetails
    where Product.ProductId=PurchaseDetails.ProductId
    group by ProductName
    order by QuantityPurchased DESC
```